# Where to download jQuery required images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can any one tell me from where i can download required images specified in .CSS file of jQuery.

Comment: can you please be more specific? As far as I know, jQuery alone does not require any image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery on its own does not require a stylesheet or images.

If you are talkign about jQuery UI, then use the downloader ( http://jqueryui.com/download ) which packages everything you need into a single zip file, including stylesheets and images used for the theme you select.

Answer (score 1):

try here

[jquery ui base theme images](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/themes/base/images)

or here

[jquery theme images](https://github.com/julienw/jquery-trap-input/find/master)